# Unable to parse json fields with multiple values so that the values match using sql

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Trying to parse json in snowflake so that the values match: `"{Codes":["VP075","VP114","VP053"],"Amount":[0.83,0.51,0.51]}`, there is usually multiple values and I tried to flatten both codes and amount out, but then the values do not match.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible to [FLATTEN](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/flatten.html) twice and match on [INDEX](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/flatten.html#output) column:

> **INDEX**    The index of the element, if it is an array; otherwise NULL.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE t(col VARIANT) AS
SELECT PARSE_JSON('{"Codes":["VP075","VP114","VP053"],"Amount":[0.83,0.51,0.51]}');

SELECT s.value::STRING AS code, s2.value::DECIMAL(10,2) AS amount
FROM t
,TABLE(FLATTEN(input => t.col, path => 'Codes')) s
,TABLE(FLATTEN(input => t.col, path => 'Amount')) s2
WHERE s.INDEX = s2.INDEX;
/*
CODE    AMOUNT
VP075   0.83
VP114   0.51
VP053   0.51
*/
```